# Excluding column from insert

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Is there a way to map a column in Code First, so that it is populated on select, but not used when inserting or updating?

If I apply the [NotMapped] annotation, the property/column is not populated, but if I do not add this annotation, when inserting, it complains that the column does not exist.

Reason I ask, is that I have a query, that performs a join and returns a value for the column, but on insertion, this column is not needed.

any idea's?

Cheers

Edit:

Just an update to explain in a little more detail what I am doing.

Previously, I had two tables,

```
Carer
    CarerID
    UserID
    IsPrimary

User
    UserID
```

But then, it was requested that a Carer can belong to more than one User, so I had to create a link table, as below.

```
UserCarer
    UserCarerID
    UserID
    CarerID
    IsPrimary
```

What I didn't want to do is, is how I've temporarily resolved this, is to create a method within my entity that then initializes another context to get the value.

Instead, I was hoping that when I selected the data, I would perform a left join to get the `IsPrimary` value from the UserCarer table thus allowing me to keep any reference to `Carer.IsPrimary`

i.e. `select * from Carer.*, UserCarer.IsPrimary from Carer left join UserCarer on Carer.CarerID = UserCarer.CarerID where UserCarer.UserID = @p0`

HTH

Comment: on top of what @Ladislav said - you seem to be doing something wrong there, I cannot think of a reasonable use. It's either a column you need or not - if it's 'calculated' then just use linq and project as Ladislav said. If you need it, where is that you 'enter' the value for it (and you could use 'default' and calculated if you need to specify that on the db side). And you could leave it be a 'null' on insert (if not needed) which is very low impact. i.e. you'd need to give us some more data.

Comment: Thanks @NSGaga, I was hoping that EF wasn't so simple and that it could support custom queries that returned data from a left join. Really, all I need is for the Property to be populated if it exists in the result set and NOT to be included on any Insert or Updates. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

That is only possible if you mark the column as computed or identity (autogenerated at insert) but it has another consequences - EF will try to select that column after update or insert so if it doesn't exist in your table you will still get an error.

It looks like you are trying to populate class which is not entity and such class cannot be used for persistence! If you have custom join in the query it means that you are doing projection / view of data and the result is most probably not entity = should not be used for saving changes.

Comment: Hi Ladislav, please see my initial post for a little more information. Hopefully it will explain why I am doing what I am doing. At the moment, I have a very ugly and inefficient method of resolving the issue but I would like to correct it. Thanks ;)